# Apache drill losing unicode in TSVs

Tags: csv, unicode, apache-drill

I'm using the text/tsv storage plugin with Apache drill and the output tsv files have ? for unicode characters. If I use the JSON storage plugin, the unicode is fine.

Something like:

URL: http://localhost:8047/query.json

Payload:

```
{
  "queryType":"SQL",
  "query": "CREATE TABLE st.`repo`.`test` AS SELECT * FROM st.`repo`.`unicode_data`"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the JVM file encoding and this is fixed.

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8